# How to post a array with $.post?

Tags: jquery, arrays, post

Here is my array:

```
arr[0]='A';
arr[1]='B';
....
```

I tried to post it this way:

```
$.post('data.php',arr,function() {

});
```

But fails to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't post an array. What you need is a hash:

```
parameters = { "Param1" : "A", "Param2" : "B" };
```

Choose a suitable name and convert your array to a hash:

```
hash = {};
$.each(arr, function(i, elem) {
 hash["Param" + i] = elem;
});
```

Comment: You can post an array. Read the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063076/how-to-post-a-array-with-post/2063090#2063090)

Comment: You can post an array, this method is exactly what people want to avoid :p

Answer (score 7):

From the [manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype):

> data (Optional)   Map, String
>
> Key/value pairs or the return value of the .serialize() function that will be sent to the server.

And from the examples in the manual:

> `$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });`

Therefore:

```
$.post("test.php", { 'arr[]': arr });
```

Comment: It is worth noting that JQuery 1.4 adds the [] in [front of your array names automatically](http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/jquery-14-param-demystified/).